# How to merge default options in Prototype Objects

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, merge

I'm looking for a simple way to merge an options object in a Prototype Class object.

I have a parent "abstract" class like this :

```
var ParentClass = Class.create({

initialize : function(someattributes, options ){
         this.someattributes = someattributes;
         this.options = Object.extend({
              foo : "foostring",
              bar : 1337
    }, options || {});
    }   
 });
```

and a children class that extends ParentClass as such :

```
var ChildrenClass = Class.create(ParentClass {

initialize : function($super, someattributes, options ){
         $super(someattributes, options);
         this.options = Object.extend({
              wheez : "wheezstring",
              bling : 123456
    }, options || {});
    }   
});
```

So the idea is to have some default options in parent class and some default options in children class
but children's class options object should be an extension of parent class options obejct;

what is the correct way to merge the two options objects when children class is initialized ?

I hope I'm clear enough ...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the the parent class initializer will have been called by the time the child class initializer is called, you can use the `options` member that is initialized by the parent:

```
Object.extend(Object.extend(this.options, {
    wheez: "wheezstring",
    bling: 123456
}), options || {});
```